# Maven exec:java and UncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: java, maven, uncaughtexceptionhandler

The following code works fine when running from java command line. However when running using exec:java I never see that line printed...Anyway to stop this behaviour?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("Uncaught exception: " + e.getMessage());

        }
    });

    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i = 1 / 0;

        }
    });
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can post your pom.xml?

Comment: Can you try adding the `-e` flag to the mvn invocation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumption is that the default UncaughtExceptionHandler is overridden by Maven itself.

From the [usage guide](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html):

> Note: The java goal doesn't spawn a new process [...] Otherwise consider using the exec goal.

Comment: Yes the exec goal works for me (prints the "Uncaught exception" message)